# Hyper-v on windows 8 core/basic

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, hyper-v

I am looking for a way to install Hyper-v on windows 8 core.
It should be possible if pro that supports hyper-v built on core.
There should be some upgrade package or hack that enables it?

Or if i really can't do that, please recommend some thing from VMware, or Oracle Virtualbox etc. which one would be more flexible and stable for single pc, I don't need and networks or remoting solution.

Comment: Hyper-V cannot be installed on Windows 8 Core. VMware and VirtualBox both have their advantages we just don't do product recommendations here at Superuser

Answer (score 1):

Why not download the free Hyper-V Server 2012.

It's Server 2012 Core + Hyper-V.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/hyper-v-server/default.aspx