# Hyper-V alternative in Windows 8.1 Single language

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

Is there any way to enable or install Hyper-V in licensed Windows 8.1 single language. I have heard it requires Pro Edition of Windows.

I want to run windows phone 8.1 emulator in Visual Studio. It need Hyper-V and its missing. Laptop is i5 Gen so virtualization is supported.

I tried VirtualBox but need to manually open virtual windows phone OS.

**My question is**: Is there any nested virtualization solution anybody tried for windows phone 8.1 emulator without Hyper-V.

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately not, however, 8.1 pro can be found on reddit for as little as $20, or from MS directly for ~$60

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 dont have hyper-v - cant use Windows Phone Emulator](http://superuser.com/questions/772078/windows-8-1-dont-have-hyper-v-cant-use-windows-phone-emulator), [Hyper-v on windows 8 core/basic](http://superuser.com/questions/645088/hyper-v-on-windows-8-core-basic) ...

Comment: @Karan: it looks like a duplicate

Comment: @TD.512: Yes, that's why I voted to close. The software rec part would be off-topic in any case.

Comment: Yeah. It's not all that hard to get a license for 8.1 pro for a little over $20

Comment: @TD.512 - A little over $20 for software that normally sells for over [$99](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-Pack-Upgrade-Online/dp/B00HG0460M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1431428885&sr=8-1&keywords=Windows+8.1+pro+pack) sonds fishy.

Comment: I know, but my copies of 8.1 all came from reddit and I've had no problems